# In mysql , looking to only show unique items from 2 queries of 2 tables with different column names

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, subquery

In mysql , looking to only show unique items from 2 queries of 2 tables with different column names. I can run them fine independently, but I want to create a list I can use in a dropdown list in PHP. I currently pull a list for Query 1 and it works fine. But I need to eliminate the choices found in Query 2. Hope that makes sense, this is not my career but only a side project !

Query 1 -

```
SELECT `driverName` 
FROM `A Drivers` 
WHERE `driverYear` = 2020
```

[image: Query 1]

Query 2 -

```
SELECT `driverA` 
FROM `user_picks` 
WHERE `userID` = 1 
and `raceYear` = 2020
```

[image: Query 2]

All of Query 2 will exist in Query 1. I don't want to show them in my result.

Thanks, Steve

Comment: Hi, Not really clear what you want here. What is the result you want to achieve. Can you show us the result you want, prefereably NOT as a picture

Comment: search for `UNION`, and how to use that in mysql. (i.e. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

Comment: @RiggsFolly - this is the result I am looking for. 

Clint Bowyer
Cole Custer
Kyle Busch
Ty Dillon

Comment: @Luuk - I tried to incorporate UNION several times prior to asking here, with no luck.

Comment: @Steve, you did not give the example 'you tried', and you did not even mention that you did, that's why i asked...

Comment: @Luuk ... I tried several over several days and just gave up, sorry. I couldn't even tell you what I tried at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NOT IN

```
SELECT `driverName` 
FROM `A Drivers` 
WHERE `driverYear` = 2020 
   AND `driverName` NOT IN (SELECT `driverA` 
                            FROM `user_picks` 
                            WHERE `userID` = 1 
                            AND `raceYear` = 2020)
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want the driver names from both tables, without duplicates. If so, you can use `union`:

```
SELECT `driverName` FROM `A Drivers` WHERE `driverYear` = 2020
UNION
SELECT `driverA` FROM `user_picks` WHERE `userID` = 1 AND `raceYear` = 2020
```

This gives you a resultset with just one column called `driverName`, without duplicates.

On the other hand, if you want records from the first query that do not exist in the results of the second query, you can use `not exists`:

```
SELECT `driverName` 
FROM `A Drivers` ad 
WHERE 
    `driverYear` = 2020
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM `user_picks` up 
        WHERE up.`userID` = 1 AND `up.raceYear` = 2020 and ip.`driverA` = ad.`driverName`
    )
```

Comment: NOT EXISTS does what I'm looking for. Thank you !